# ST_GEOMETRY points: get attribute of intersecting polygon

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, intersection, spatial-join, oracle-dbms, st-geometry

I have an SDE.ST_GEOEMTRY point feature class.

I want to create an SQL query from the points. The query would perform a spatial join/intersection with an SDE.ST_GEOMETRY polygon feature class. An attribute would be returned from the polygon that the points intersect.

- The polygons don't overlap, so a point would never intersect multiple polygons.
- The query would be output to a static table on a schedule. So performance is not a major concern.

Is there a way to do this with SDE.ST_GEOMETRY functions? I've looked at the [function list](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/a-quick-tour-of-sql-functions-used-with-st-geometry.htm), but I don't see any spatial operations that return an attribute.

Comment: By what do you mean "don't see any spatial operations that return an attribute"?  SQL queries haven't really changed since 3.0 days.  Theme-on-theme SQL query is unchanged, and still has the requirement to share a SpatialReference between the tables.

Comment: It's not clear why you have to take the ST_PointOnSurface of a buffer of a point (which really ought to snap back to the start, but *really* slowly), but yes, this is just a simple ST_Intersects join.

Answer (score 3):

I think I figured it out. I just hadn't done a spatial join with SQL until now.

I ended up doing the spatial join on a line FC instead of a point FC (but I convert the lines to midpoints in the subquery).

```
--Spatial join between line midpoints and and a polygon FC. 
--Returns the zone ID from the intersecting polygon.

select 
    ba.ba_id,
    z.zone
from 
    (
    select
        ba_id,
        --Get the line's midpoint to avoid the line overlapping multiple polygons 
        --More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65723767/10936066
        sde.st_pointonsurface(sde.st_buffer(shape, 0.05)) as midpoint 
    from
        .barrier --line FC
    ) ba
left join 
    zones z --polygon FC
    on sde.st_intersects(ba.midpoint, z.shape) = 1
```

[image]

---

Source: [What's the proper way to do a spatial join in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47021292/whats-the-proper-way-to-do-a-spatial-join-in-oracle)

Note: The datatype in that post is SDO_GEOMETRY, not SDE.ST_GEOMETRY.

Comment: Upon further testing, the way I calculated the line midpoints doesn't seem to be a good approach. The midpoint doesn't get placed at the correct position along the line (especially curved lines). So, I think a true midpoint calculation would be better (example: a linear referencing solution).